# Scripts failing to update with XAMPP

Tags: apache-http-server, script, cache, xampp

I've just installed XAMPP and I'm playing around with it.

When I run a simple PHP script:

```
<? echo"test";?>
```

everything is OK.

But when i update that script:

```
<? echo"test2";?>
```

I still get the old version executed ("test")...

Looks like some sort of caching is going on. I've looked in my `http.conf` and every line with the word `cache` is commented out.

Anyone have any idea on how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was down to the version I was using. Downgraded to 6.8 and it worked fine.